# Javascript/HTML How to reference a div element by its hash, get its contents and paste its contents to other div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I normally program in Excel VBA and sometimes C# and for me javascript is unfamiliar so forgive me if this is easy.

I have an html document which I would like to populate over time with notes about Economics.  Also in the document I have some javascript that uses JQuery treeview which I got from a Youtube tutorial.  It is a requirement for me that everything is in one document so that deployment is really simple.

The HTML document has a treeview section (actually there are two but never mind that), a topic viewer section (which eventually I get placed on the right) and a list of all topics which is "production" would be initially hidden.

In the treeview I want each treeview node to have an  anchor ref that points to a div element in the all topics section.  I'm the ID attribute so I can use a relative reference syntax hash # .  When the treeview node is clicked I want Javascript code to search the document using the hash from the node and locate the the topic div.  Then I want to grab the topic contents (innerhtml probably) and paste them to the topic viewer's div contents (also innerhtml probably).

So what I am building is a ruidimentary one page wikipedia of my Economics notes.

So I think I'm two lines away from success.  I got stuck because I don't know how to traverse the DOM, I tried some XPATH type syntax which I use when working with XML but it doesn't work here.

I'm having difficulty so please help me over the line, thanks.  Code is attached.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>One Page</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script>
        // Source code initially borrowed from this helpful chap Jiansen Lu http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZFkWDGyZBs
        $(function () {
            $('div.mytree div:has(div)').addClass('parent');
            $('div.mytree div').click(function () {
                var thistree = $(this);
                thistree.children('div').toggle();
                thistree.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');

                // does the clicked link have an anchor
                var anchor = thistree.children('a');
                if (anchor.length > 0) {
                    // we got an anchor so grab id 
                    var topic = anchor[0].hash; // children('#href');

                    // and grab contents
                    //---GOT STUCK HERE
                    var topicContents = $('div.AllTopics div[@id="' + topic + '"]');

                    // paste contents to topic viewer div
                    //NOT WORKING $('div.TopicViewer').innerhtml = topicContents.innerhtml;
                }

                return false;
            });
        });


    </script>
    <style>
        div.mytree div {
            padding-left: 15px;
            background: transparent url(http://www3.telus.net/jianlu58/bullet.gif) no-repeat top left;
        }

            div.mytree div.parent div {
                display: none;
                cursor: default;
            }

            div.mytree div.parent {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: transparent url(http://www3.telus.net/jianlu58/plus.gif) no-repeat top left;
            }

            div.mytree div.expanded {
                background: transparent url(http://www3.telus.net/jianlu58/minus.gif) no-repeat top left;
            }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="mytree" style="padding:22px;border:2px solid #ccc;width:10%;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
        <div>
            Theory
            <div>Introduction</div>
            <div>
                Economics
                <div>
                    Economists
                    <div><a href="#Cantillon_Richard">Cantillon, R</a></div>
                    <div><a href="#Thornton_Henry">Thorton, H</a></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Schools
                    <div>Keynesian</div>
                    <div>Austrian</div>
                    <div>Marxian</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Journals
                    <div>American Economic Review</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Glossary
                    <div><a href="#CantillonEffect">Cantillon Effect</a></div>
                    <div>Ricardian Equivalence</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                Finance
                <div>
                    Institutions
                    <div>
                        Public
                        <div>IMF</div>
                        <div>World Bank</div>
                        <div>BIS</div>
                        <div>WTO</div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mytree" style="padding:22px;border:2px solid #ccc;width:10%;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
        <div>
            Market Data
            <div>
                Static Data
                <div>Sources</div>
                <div>
                    Central Banks
                    <div>Bank of England</div>
                    <div>Federal Reserve</div>
                    <div>ECB</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Data Categories
                    <div>FX Rates</div>
                    <div>Interest Rates</div>
                    <div>Equities</div>
                    <div>Commodities</div>
                    <div>Wages</div>
                    <div>Inflation</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                Dynamic Data
                <div>FX Rates</div>
                <div>Interest Rates</div>
                <div>Equities</div>
                <div>Commodities</div>
                <div>Wages</div>
                <div>Inflation</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="topic_viewer" style="top:50px;padding:22px;border:2px solid #ccc;width:90%;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
        Click on a topic on the left and this pane will be populated
    </div>

    <div class="AllTopics">
        <!-- in production we'll use display:none to hide all this content -->
        <div id="AustrianTheoryOfBusinessCycles">
            <h1>Austrian Theory Of Business Cycles</h1>
            <a href="https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/wp/2002/wp0202.pdf">The Austrian Theory of Business Cycles: Old Lessons For Moden Economic Policy?</a>
        </div>


        <div id="Cantillon_Richard">
            <h1>Richard Cantillon</h1>
            <h2>1680-1815</h2>
            <a href="https://mises.org/books/paper_credit_thornton.pdf">An Enquiry into the Nature and Effects of the Paper Credit of Great Britain (written 1730 published 1755)</a>
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Cantillon">Richard Cantillon Wikipedia </a>
            <a href="http://mises.org/daily/4190">The Business Cycle Explained in 1755 - Richard Cantillon - Mises Daily</a>
            <a href=" #cantilloneffect">Cantillon Effect</a>
        </div>
        <div id="CantillonEffect">
            <h1>Cantillon Effects</h1>
            <a href="http://wiki.mises.org/wiki/Richard_Cantillon#Cantillon_effects">Cantillon effects are the real fundamental changes in resource allocation that result from changing relative prices between the time of the creation of new money and the full adjustment to the increase in supply.</a>
            <a href="http://www.zerohedge.com/news/guest-post-cantillon-effect">Guest Post: The Cantillon Effect | Zero Hedge</a>
        </div>
        <div id="Thornton_Henry">
            <h1>Henry Thornton</h1>
            <h2>1760-1815</h2>
            <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Thornton_%28reformer%29">Thornton_Henry Wikipedia </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. You can use the jQuery attr syntax instead of dropping into the raw DOM element with `anchor[0]`. Also you should use jQuery's `preventDefault` method on the jQuery event object, instead of returning false. Finally you can just use the method `html` to get the contents instead of innerHTML:

```
$('.mytree div').click(function (e) { // 'e' is a jQuery event
  e.preventDefault(); // instead of return false

  var thistree = $(this);
  thistree.children('div').toggle();
  thistree.filter('.parent').toggleClass('expanded');

  var anchor = thistree.children('a');

  if (anchor.length > 0) {
    var topic = anchor.attr('href'); // instead of anchor[0].hash

    var topicContents = $(topic); // jquery ID selector
    $('div.TopicViewer').html( topicContents.html() );
  }
});
```

Documentation:

[jQuery Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

[jQuery attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a couple of tweaks.  I needed to remove the '#' because it ended up double the number of hashes.  Also, I had to edit the class name on the topic viewer div so it matched your code sample.   Great stuff, thanks.

Comment: Oops. Yep. Updated the answer to remove that stray '#'. My bad. Also, you can shorten this code a little. I didn't use it in my example, since it makes the explanation harder to read, but you could do something like: `contents = $( anchor.attr('href') ).html()` then `$('div.TopicViewer').html( contents )`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery it is really easy to grab a div by its ID - just do $('#my_id') and that will give you a jQuery representation of this div:

```
<div id="my_id">
```

So to copy HTML from a source

```
<div id="src_id">
```

to a destination

```
<div id="dest_id">
```

would look something like this:

```
$('#dest_id').html(
    $('#src_id').html()
)
```

A really useful link for you to read would be:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

which will tell you all about jQuery selectors. Given you know XPath, you'll soon pick up how to use jQuery to access the DOM.